# Rounding differences on Windows vs Unix based system in sprintf

Tags: c++, c, windows, unix, rounding-error

I have problem on UNIX based systems sprintf does not round up properly value.

For example

```
double tmp = 88888888888885.875
char out[512];
```

Thats 88,888,888,888,885.875 just to be easier on eyes.
I am giving such specific and big example because it seems it works fine on smaller numbers.

I am trying to use it in following way

```
sprintf(out, "%021.2f", tmp);
printf("out = %s\n", tmp);
```

On windows this results in:

```
out = 000088888888888885.88
```

On for example AIX, but shows in Linux as well:

```
out = 000088888888888885.87
```

Why is this happening?
Any ideas and how to make it behave same way on Win/Unix

Thanks

Comment: erm, http://www.ideone.com/UVtft reports `.88`, my local SuseLinux reports the same...

Comment: What CPUs are you using for each OS?

Comment: On Linux (Debian 5) AMD64 I get `000088888888888885.88`

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994764/rounding-doubles-5-sprintf. A difference between your fraction (.875) and his fraction (.555) is that yours can be expressed exactly in binary; it is 7/8.

Comment: On most computers using 64-bit IEEE `double` s, your two `out` strings are both equal to the original (exact) value of `tmp`.

Comment: this is 32 bit box.. CPU on win box is Intel Xeon(R) x5550 2.6GHz running windows vista and VS2010... on Aix its XLC compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [bug report](http://sources.redhat.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4943) for glibc with a problem very similar to yours. The main conclusion (in comment 46) here is that double is not a 15-decimal-digit number and you should not expect it to work like that.

As a workaround you can add something small to your numbers to make them round better. But this solution is not general because it depends on number ranges you deal with.

Another workaround can be multiplying to prepare them for rounding, then rounding (e.g. `2597.625*100 = 259762.5 -> 259763 = 2597.63*100`)

However I think there must be smarter workarounds.

Comment: I did not use your workaround but the top part is what i needed thanks

Answer (score 1):

What floating point representations are used by your processor and your compiler?

Not all processors use the same way to represent floating-point values and even compilers may choose different floating-point representation methods (I think the Microsoft C++ compiler even has options to choose the representation).

The page http://www.quadibloc.com/comp/cp0201.htm gives an overview of some of the floating-point representations (although they seem to be rather old architectures shown there).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b34tf65.aspx describes how Microsoft Visual C++ stores floating-point values.  I couldn't find immediately what representation is used by AIX or Linux.

Additinally, every compiler has options that let you indicate how you want to work with floating-point operations.  Do you want them to be correct as possible (but possibly somewhat slower)?  Or do you want floating-point operations to be fast as possible (but possibly less correct)?

Comment: MSVC can't choose the representation, it's options are about the optimizations it performs on floating-point arithmetic and methods.

Comment: Here's an interesting related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961442/different-math-rounding-behaviour-between-linux-mac-os-x-and-windows

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using `double` which has accuracy limitations, meaning, your `88888888888885.875` is probably being rounded to something else internally.

See more info [in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420752/is-double-multiplication-broken-in-net), in [blogs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/05/why-do-computers-suck-at-math.html) or in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).

Comment: Yes by why is the double being rounded differently on the different OS's? Of course it has accuracy limitations, that's why he is getting different answers.

Comment: It can vary from the box's architecture to some polishing being done by libc's printf. As you can see from comments to question, even within the same OS (Linux) it behaves differently, because essentially there's no warranty that it should behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

On an IEEE 754 conformant implementation, it should print `88888888888885.88` in the default rounding mode. This has nothing to do with floating point precision since the value is exactly representable; it's simply a matter of `printf`'s rounding to 2 places after the decimal point. No idea why you're seeing `88888888888885.87` on some systems.

Comment: The OP might like to try omitting the `sprintf` (and just assigning directly to a double) to verify that this is happening in `printf`.