# printf rounding behavior for doubles

Tags: c++, floating-point, printf, rounding

Can someone explain this behavior? I am well aware of machine-level representation of floating point numbers. This seems to be related to printf and its formats.
Both numbers are represented exactly by floating-point notation (check: multiplying by 64 gives an integer).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  double x1=108.765625;
  printf("%34.30f\n", x1);
  printf("%9.5f\n", x1);
  printf("%34.30f\n", x1*64);

  double x2=108.046875;
  printf("%34.30lf\n", x2);
  printf("%9.5f\n", x2);
  printf("%34.30f\n", x2*64);
}
```

Output:

```
> 108.765625000000000000000000000000
> 108.76562
> 6961.000000000000000000000000000000
> 108.046875000000000000000000000000
> 108.04688
> 6915.000000000000000000000000000000
```

Note, the first number gets rounded down, and the second one gets rounded up.

Comment: You might be interested in my article http://www.exploringbinary.com/inconsistent-rounding-of-printed-floating-point-numbers/ . Some implementations use "round-half-away-from-zero" instead of "round-half-to-even".

Comment: It appears that Microsoft changed their default rounding behaviour some time between VS 2010 and VS2015. I just upgraded from one to the other and got some very annoying and subtle bugs. [This blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/06/18/c-runtime-crt-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-14-ctp1/) is probably meant to highlight the change, but you'd be forgiven for missing it entirely.

Comment: it depends on implementation [Rounding differences on Windows vs Unix based system in sprintf](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4649554/995714), [C++ Rounding behavior consistency for ties with sprintf](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31142600/995714)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's "round half to even" or "Banker's rounding". The last digit of the rounded representation is chosen to be even if the number is exactly half way between the two.

http://linuxgazette.net/144/misc/lg/a_question_of_rounding_in_issue_143.html:
"For the GNU C library, the rounding rule used by printf() is "bankers rounding" or "round to even". This is more correct than some other C libraries, as the C99 specification says that conversion to decimal should use the currently selected IEEE rounding mode (default bankers rounding)."

Comment: The author of the linked article is incompetent. "Binary and decimal radix do not share the same set of irrational numbers" - that's nonsense. Rationality/irrationality is independent of base.

Comment: @R.. Indeed. But the quoted passage of the article is correct, as the author painfully learned in his [bug report](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4943).

Comment: "not all finite decimal expansions have finite binary expansions"

Answer (score 0):

The `%9.5f` output gives the number with 5 digits after the decimal dot which is the nearest of the source number.

Comment: The point of the question, I believe, is: what if the source number is exactly halfway between two possible outputs?