# sprintf formats not as expected

Tags: ruby, printf

I've got a problem with rounding using `sprintf`. I get passed `'%0.0f'` as the format. `sprintf` rounds not as expected: `0.5` should be rounded to `1`, instead it rounds to `0`, which is against the general rounding rule, whereas `1.5`, `2.5` etc. is being rounded correctly:

```
sprintf('%0.0f', 0.5)
=> "0"


sprintf('%0.0f', 1.5)
=> "2"
```

Why is this so and how can I achieve my expected behaviour?

Comment: Actually, every even number rounds wrong - 2.5 gives 2, for example.

Comment: Relevant: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12548 and https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12958

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sprintf` performs *banker's rounding*, which rounds 0.5 to the nearest even number. This method is often used by statisticians, as it doesn't artificially inflate averages like *half-up rounding*.

The `Float#round` method (in Ruby 2.4+) accepts a parameter which can be one of:

- `half: :up` (the default)
- `half: :down`
- `half: :even` (banker's rounding)

Apparently you are expecting `round`'s default, so you can just do a `.round` to your number before printing.

Comment: _"sprintf performs banker's rounding"_ – oh indeed, is this documented?

Comment: @Stefan Not sure, but the default `round` behavior [almost got changed](http://www.rubyguides.com/2016/12/new-ruby-features/) to banker's rounding in Ruby 2.4, but at the last minute it was reverted. Too much of a breaking change, I guess.

Comment: @Stefan Ruby almost certainly inherits it from C's `printf` which specifies it in the standard https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357192/printf-rounding-behavior-for-doubles

Comment: @Max. I think you're on to something. According to the [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html), "The low-order digit shall be rounded in an implementation-defined manner." But it appears that most C implementations use [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) which specifies banker's rounding.

Comment: @Max so depending on my C library, it could round either way?

Comment: @Stefan glancing at the source it looks like it might not actually call C's sprintf but instead reimplements the behavior of it. I would just call it interpreter-implementation-specific and leave it at that.

Answer (score 2):

> how can I achieve my expected behaviour?

Round the float before you give it to sprintf:

```
2.4.0 :001 > sprintf('%0.0f', 0.5.round)
 => "1" 

2.4.0 :002 > sprintf('%0.0f', 1.5.round)
 => "2"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior for `printf`. The default rounding mode is to round to the nearest valid value, and in case of a tie to pick the even number. Since `0.5` is treated as being in exactly the middle of `0` and `1`, it tends to `0` because it is the even number.