# Not getting desired outputs, numbers not rounding

Tags: c

Not getting the values I want when I test my code.

Tried applying .2 to my %lf's and changing to doubles or floats.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main (void){

double hours;
float grossPay;
double netPay;

const double rate = 7.25;

double federal;
double state;
float fica;
double medicare;
double deductions;



printf("Please enter hours worked per week: ");
scanf("%lf", &hours);

grossPay = hours * rate;

//calculated pay from input
printf("Hours per Week: %.2lf\n", hours);
printf("Hourly Rate: $%.2lf\n", rate);
printf("Gross Pay: $%.2lf\n", grossPay);

//calculations for deductions

federal = grossPay * 0.10;
state = grossPay * 0.014;
fica = grossPay * 0.062;
medicare = grossPay * 0.0145;

deductions = federal + state + fica + medicare;

netPay = grossPay - deductions;

printf("Net Pay: %lf\n\n", netPay);

printf("Deductions\n");
printf("Federal: $%lf\n", federal);
printf("State: $%lf\n", state);
printf("FICA: $%1.2lf\n", fica);
printf("Medicare: $%lf\n", medicare);




return 0;
}
```

My desired outputs are when I enter 30 for hours, the deductions should correspond with 
 $21.75
 $3.05
 $13.49
 $3.15
, with a net pay of $176.06

**edit**
the values I was getting with 30 hours was
$21.75, $3.04, $13.48, $3.15 if I used %.2lf

Comment: [man round](https://linux.die.net/man/3/round)

Comment: 1) do not use `float`.  2) use `"%.2f"`.  .

Comment: "Not getting the values I want when I test my code." --> post what you were getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10357192/9200752)

It uses "round half to even" or "bankers' rounding" rule. So the result of rounding `13.485` with two digits after fraction, is `13.48` since `8` is the **nearest even digit** in choosing between `8` and `9`.

And also `3.045` will be rounded to `3.04`.