# R: locpoly is incorrectly returning NaN

Tags: r, ubuntu, lapack, blas

Running the following code gives me a `NaN`:

```
library(KernSmooth) 
x <- c(5.84155992364115, 1.55292112974119, 0.0349665318792623, 3.93053647398094,
       3.42790577684633, 2.9715553006801, 0.837108410045353, 2.872476865277, 
       3.89232548092257, 0.206399650539628) 
y <- c(0.141415317472329, 1.34799648955049, 0.0297566221758204, 
       -0.966736679061812, 0.246306732122746, 0.557982376254723, 
       0.740542828791083, 0.162336127802977, -0.428804158514744, 
       0.691280978689863) 

locpoly(x, y, bandwidth = 0.4821232, gridsize = 12, degree = 1)[['y']]
```

I get

```
[1]  0.3030137  0.6456624  0.9530586  1.1121106  0.8120947  0.4441603
[7]  0.1425592 -0.3600028 -0.7840411 -1.0517612 -1.2690134        NaN
```

On another computer, I get the same, except I get `-0.7270521` instead of `NaN`. I am guessing that most of you will also get that. So the question is how do I fix my broken system? Does this have to do with my LAPACK or LIBBLAS?

Note that both computers mentioned above use Ubuntu. The one that gave `NaN` uses Ubuntu 13.10, the one that gave a number is on 12.04.

EDIT:

My new suspicion is that it is a floating point calculation issue:
A local polynomial regression is just a weighted linear regression, where the weights decrease the further the point is away from the point of evaluation, in this case 5.84. One should note that the bandwidth is small so a first thought is that there are no points within the bandwidth. However, locpoly uses a Gaussian kernel, so that all points have strictly positive weight. My guess is that the weights are so small though that rounding or floating point calculation can be a problem. I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: I get `NaN` also, running Linux.

Comment: @RScriv thanks for the confirmation. I guess I'm not the only one. I'm also on Linux. I updated my OS info above.

Comment: I get NaN OSX R 3.03.   Now before we all go diving into LAPACK, can someone confirm which value is the "correct" one?

Comment: Same here. R3.0.3 on OS X 10.9.2 and I get `NaN` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am using Windows 7 and R 3.0, I get:

```
 > locpoly(x, y, bandwidth = 0.4821232, gridsize = 12, degree = 1)[['y']]
 [1]  0.3030137  0.6456624  0.9530586  1.1121106  0.8120947
 [6]  0.4441603  0.1425592 -0.3600028 -0.7840411 -1.0517612
[11] -1.2690134 -2.8078788
```

So your issue wasn't there. However if I use R 3.0 on Ubuntu 13.04 (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-23-generic x86_64) I get:

```
 > locpoly(x, y, bandwidth = 0.4821232, gridsize = 12, degree = 1)[['y']]

 [1]  0.3030137  0.6456624  0.9530586  1.1121106  0.8120947  0.4441603
 [7]  0.1425592 -0.3600028 -0.7840411 -1.0517612 -1.2690134        NaN
```

I tried experimenting and was able to get numbers very similar to what I got in Windows 7 by using:

```
> locpoly(round(x,3), round(y,3), bandwidth = 0.4821232, gridsize = 12, degree = 1)[['y']]

 [1]  0.3032295  0.6459197  0.9533132  1.1121400  0.8118960  0.4437407
 [7]  0.1422658 -0.3604210 -0.7848982 -1.0531299 -1.2710219 -0.7269588
```

So I hope that is able to solve your second problem.

In order to figure out why I was able to get non-NaN answer with Windows, but not Ubuntu, we can look at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/KernSmooth/index.html and notice that:

MacOS X binary:  KernSmooth_2.23-10.tgz
Windows binary:  KernSmooth_2.23-11.zip

Naturally there are two different versions, but the Windows binary is one version further than MacOS X binary. I checked out the sourcecode for the functions in Ubuntu and Windows and they look to be the same. However, I did find this [Rounding differences on Windows vs Unix based system in sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649554/rounding-differences-on-windows-vs-unix-based-system-in-sprintf) showing that there is a reported bug for differences in rounding between unix and windows. Although that was asked 3 years ago. So I would say the difference might be OS or version for KernSmooth (would lean toward OS as others have also encountered that issue)

Comment: This does not answer the question. If you use `round` but specify `bandwidth = 0.3821232` the problem comes back. The `round` just effectively increases the bandwidth (in this particular example). Nonetheless, thank you for your effort and I think you've given the most information so I'll accept it.

Comment: Thank you for choosing my answer. I'm sorry that it didn't fully answer your questions, but its the best I could do. A final step you could take would be to email Brian Ripley <ripley@stats.ox.ac.uk> who maintains the package.

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer, but wanted to post a graph.  I'm still not clear on what you expected to get from `locpoly`, but here it is.

```
Rgames> foo<-locpoly(x, y, bandwidth = 0.4821232, gridsize = 12, degree = 1)
Rgames> foo
$x
 [1] 0.03496653 0.56283866 1.09071078 1.61858291 2.14645504 2.67432716
 [7] 3.20219929 3.73007142 4.25794354 4.78581567 5.31368780 5.84155992

$y
 [1]  0.3030137  0.6456624  0.9530586  1.1121106  0.8120947  0.4441603
 [7]  0.1425592 -0.3600028 -0.7840411 -1.0517612 -1.2690134        NaN
```

[image]  My suspicion is that last point on the far right diverges for the fitting parameters in use, and it was dumb luck that you got a non-NaN value under any OS.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, Carl. Do you have anything to back up that suspicion? (I definitely don't mean that as a challenge, just curious if you have any insight.) What do you mean by "diverges" here? You got me thinking about potential problems and my guess is this is a floating point calculation issue. I'll add my guesses with attempted intuition to my question.

Comment: @XuWang The trend of the red dots (locpoly outout) is clearly down, away from the last input value.  That makes me believe the fitting function either ignores or cannot "bend" back to the input data.

Comment: I see your intuition. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Windows 7, R 3.0.1.

It does seem to be a floating point issue, but because of `max(x)`: changing the first entry in `x`(which happens to be it's `max`) from `5.84155992364115` to `5.841559923` your `NaN` becomes  `Inf`, and to `5.84155992` your `NaN`becomes `-0.7261049`.

Also setting the option `truncate` to `FALSE` changes the ouput considerably:

```
locpoly(x, y, bandwidth = 0.4821232, gridsize = 12, degree = 1, truncate=F)[['y']]
[1]  0.3030137  0.6456624  0.9530586  1.1121106  0.8120947  0.4441603  0.1425592 -0.3600028 -0.7449278 -0.3872891 -0.1235228  0.1414153
```

which I wouldn't have anticipated since you didn't specify `range.x`.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for a local polynomial of degree 1 (Requires 2 points to fit, minimum) and there is only one point local to 5.84155992364115. The real question is, why didn't it give you a nice error telling you to up the bandwidth. Nudge it up to 0.5 and it all works.

Comment: Local polynomial regressions weight every observation if the normal kernel is used. The point is that the weights are extremely small. But in theory this regression is correctly specified. For a good reference, read http://www.amazon.com/Local-Polynomial-Modelling-Its-Applications/dp/0412983214/ref=sr_1_1/192-9646761-7959750?ie=UTF8&qid=1395898908&sr=8-1&keywords=local+polynomial+regression

Comment: Usually software will add a cut point beyond which the kernel is set to 0. In the case of a normal density, 4 sigma sounds about right. I can't read FORTRAN or C, so I didn't look at the actual function to see if such cut point is applied, but you could test it out with other examples. Try adding -14, -15, -17.5, -19.5,-20.5,-21.5 to your X and 1:6 to your Y and you get and error that complains about BW. Again, that's what I'd expect here.

Answer (score 0):

I will like to put it differently,

I am not regular user of ubuntu, but know NaN(Not a Number) which was started by Java!

First I will say update [Lapack](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lapack)
And make sure all files are installed correctly ([Recent Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lapack/+bug/1097231))

if some file is missing and the number is not processed well.

Divide by Zero (or Invalid result due to missing library) can cause NAN in result.

I don't think ubuntu has any problem with this as this.

Please specify version of LAPACK from better understanding.(including Ubuntu is 32 or 64 bit and LAPACK is 32 or 64bit)

I hope this will help.

Comment: I am indeed suspecting divide by 0 because the weights are so small.

Comment: If its divide by Zero, should not work on other OS/ System. So I will not say that.. :)