# C++ Rounding behavior consistency for ties with sprintf

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, printf

I have a C++ program that runs on both Windows/Linux.  On Windows the program is compiled with Visual Studio 2012 and Linux it is compiled with GCC.  When converting doubles to strings using sprintf Visual Studio is using a different rounding method than the GCC compiler for ties - ie decimals ending in a 5.

Visual Studio compiler appears to perform [round half away from zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_away_from_zero) while GCC does [round even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) aka bankers rounding.

Round even is the desired behavior.

Is it possible to change the rounding behavior used for sprintf format strings in visual studio / windows? As I need to make the rounding behave consistently between the two.

Here is a small sample C++ program that illustrates the above described behavior:

```
int main()
{   
   char buffer[100];

   double x;
   for (x = -0.5; x <= 10.5; x += 1.0)
   {
      sprintf(buffer,"%4g %.0f\n", x, x);

      std::cout << buffer;
   }  

   return 0;
}
```

Windows output.  Numbers are rounded away from zero:

[image: windows]

OSX output compiled using xCode.  Numbers are rounded using round even towards the even number:

[image: osx]

OSX output:

Comment: You might want to look into this article and its comments: http://www.exploringbinary.com/inconsistent-rounding-of-printed-floating-point-numbers/

Comment: you can always use your own {*}printf functions

Comment: [Rounding differences on Windows vs Unix based system in sprintf](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4649554/995714)

Answer (score 3):

This is implementation defined behavior from the draft C11 standard section `7.21.6.1` The fprintf function which covers `sprintf` with respect for format specifiers and also C++ since the C++ standard relies on the C standard for stdio functions, it says for the `f` format specifier:

> The value is rounded to
>   the appropriate number of digits.

this is also covered by [defect report 211](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_211.htm) which added the following:

> The accuracy of the floating-point operations ( +, -, *, /) and of the library functions in  and  that return floating-point results is implementation defined, as is the accuracy of the conversion between floating-point internal representations and string representations performed by the libray routine in ,  and . The implementation may state that the accuracy is unknown.

the article [Inconsistent Rounding of Printed Floating-Point Numbers](http://www.exploringbinary.com/inconsistent-rounding-of-printed-floating-point-numbers/) covers this inconsistency in great details and mentions that:

> glibc printf() has been updated to take the current IEEE rounding mode into account. This was done in version 2.17; I just tested it on version 2.18. In doing it this way of course, round-to-nearest/round-half-away-from-zero is still not an option, so this doesn’t help you make its output consistent with other platforms.

but as said this does not help with cross platform consistency.