# Round in C with N digits after decimal point

Tags: c, math, rounding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rounding Number to 2 Decimal Places in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c)

I have not found a function with a signature `double round(double d, int digits)` like [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx) in c.
When i try to build i get a error:

> error: too many arguments to function 'round'

How can I round in C with N digits after the decimal point?

Comment: @melpomene, thanks i have found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994764/rounding-doubles-5-sprintf but i need to get return value not only print it

Comment: Decimal point is relevant for display. One could round to the nearest negative power of ten - but - why would you want such a thing?

Comment: **Voting to re-open**.  The cited "duplicate" is a special case, requiring  rounding to only 2 decimal places.  This question asks the more general case of rounding to an arbitrary number of decimal places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using recursion (which is going to be slow for some values of digits)

```
#include <math.h>
double my_round(double x, unsigned int digits) {
  if (digits > 0) {
    return my_round(x*10.0, digits-1)/10.0;
  }
  else {
    return round(x);
  }
}
```

A method likely to be somewhat faster, but which relies on a single call to the slow `pow` function:

```
#include <math.h>

double my_round(double x, unsigned int digits) {
    double fac = pow(10, digits);
    return round(x*fac)/fac;
}
```

An even faster method is to precompute a lookup table with the likely powers and use that instead of `pow`.

```
#include <math.h>

double fac[];  // population of this is left as an exercise for the reader

double my_round(double x, unsigned int digits) {
    return round(x*fac[digits])/fac[digits];
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that this doesn't actually compile as C, but would as C++.

Comment: using recursion where simple arithmetics would suffice?

Comment: @PavelRadzivilovsky: which is why in my original response I also included the more efficient method.

Comment: I would remove the recursion. It is like going to a chemist thru the moon..

Comment: I'm very surprised this even compiles in C, much less "nicely work[s]".  [To be specific, I'm surprised the compiler didn't object to `round` having two different call signatures, and thus conflicting types.]

Comment: Yes definitely works, i have tested first and second methods.

Comment: @DSM: fixed the naming reference... it's been a while since I've done straight C programming.

Comment: In the recursive version `my_round(1,1)` gives result `10`.

Comment: @Henry: Forgot to divide by 10... fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst "answerd" gives a decent answer, here's one that works for arbitrarily large numbers:

```
double round1(double num, int N) {
      ASSERT(N > 0);
      double p10 = pow(10,N);
      return round(num* p10) / p10;
}
```

Of course, as stated, floating point numbers don't have a set number of decimal digits, and this is NOT guaranteed to PRINT as 3.70000 if you call `printf("%8.5f", round1(3.7519, 1));` for example.

Answer (score 0):

here's a (very) simple function,

```
double round1(double num, int N) {
      int temp=(int) num*pow(10,N); 
      double roundedN= temp/pow(10,N);
      return roundedN;
}
```

Comment: This does not round, it truncates. Moreover `pow` is an expensive operation, store the result instead of invoking it twice.

Comment: May be i'm doing something wroing but i test it repeatedly, it not work.

Comment: @Henry, `pow` for integer power could be implemented efficiently (with O(log n) complexity). So in this case it's cheap.

Comment: @Barmaley.exe, you are right, but thats still more than O(1) for an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

In C standard, such function does not exist. Anyway, you can write your own.

```
#include <math.h>

/* Round `n` with `c` digits after decimal point. */

double nround (double n, unsigned int c)
{
    double marge = pow (10, c);
    double up    = n * marge;
    double ret   = round (up) / marge;

    return ret;
}
```

See also the comments above about floating points "decimal point".